# How to identify element using link name in a onclick html tag?

Tags: xpath, css-selectors

How to identify element using link name in below HTML tag?

I have already identified path using XPATH/CSS using direct search like `css(#SearchMenu > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1))`. But in our environment, location of the element will change frequently. Could someone help me to identify element using name of the link (StoreNet).

```
<div class="search">
<div class="search-dropdown" onclick="showHideUtilMenu(event, 'SearchMenu');">
<span id="searchoptionValue">Consumer</span>
<span id="dropdownarrow"></span>
<span id="searchurlValue" style="display: none;">http://</span>
<div id="SearchMenu" class="utility-menu combobox">`enter code here`
    <ul class="menu-link">
        <li class="menu-link">
            <a onclick="getSearchOption('StoreNet','http://store.net/test);">StoreNet</a>
        </li>
```

Comment: Which element do you want? SearchMenu?

Comment: I want to search element inside <a> tag using name of the link StoreNet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath expression `//a` will get you the content of `<a>`. The expression `div[//a='StoreNet']` will return the `<div>` element that contains a `<a>` containing `StoreNet`.

This expression will return the contents of the `<a>` inside the `<div>` with an `id` of `SearchMenu`, independent of how many other nesting levels of html exist between them:

```
//div[@id='SearchMenu']//a
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML isn't enough for analyzing the structure.

Do you have many similar `<a>` with same `onclick` or text?

For now, I can suggest the followings, which might not suit your needs, as lack of context.

CSS Selectors:

```
#SearchMenu a[onclick*='store.net/test']
#SearchMenu a[onclick*='StoreNet']
```

XPaths:

```
.//div[@id='SearchMenu']//a[contains(@onclick, 'store.net/test')]
.//div[@id='SearchMenu']//a[contains(@onclick, 'StoreNet')]
.//div[@id='SearchMenu']//a[text()='StoreNet']
```

Comment: Thank you. #SearchMenu a[onclick*='StoreNet'] is worked without any issue.